# cant able to make my package

Tags: ros, roslaunch, package, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I'm just tried out talker/listener code in beginner tutorial

but while I make
I got the following error
Could you please help me to find out the solution

```
 mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package beginner_tutorials
[rosbuild] Error from directory check: /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/check_same_directories.py  /home/utp/robotics/beginner_tutorials
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/bin/check_same_directories.py", line 46, in <module>
    raise Exception
Exception
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/private.cmake:102 (message):
  [rosbuild] rospack found package "beginner_tutorials" at "", but the
  current directory is "/home/utp/robotics/beginner_tutorials".
  You should double-check your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to ensure that packages are
  found in the correct precedence order.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:177 (_rosbuild_check_package_location)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57237/cant-able-to-make-my-package/) by [unais](https://answers.ros.org/users/4285/unais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 313 on 2013-03-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please learn to format code and messages correctly, that way people will find it easier to read and possibly be more willing to help you.

Have you created the [workspace with rosws](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment)?

The error is saying rosbuild can't find your package among the current ROS tree.
That's to say that in all the configured environment, there is nothing that points to your package.

Usually to solve such a problem you have to manually add the path:

```
$ rosws set /path/to/your/package
```

close and reopen the terminal and it should build.

In the future to check the paths in your workspace you can

```
$ rosws info
```

and to remove any

```
$ rosws remove
```

---

Originally posted by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) with karma: 859 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1